# Call main view controller from container view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uicontainerview

I have a container view controller with its own view controller class and some UI components. Some events of this container view controller needs to call the main view controller. I'm not able to find how to do it.

```
class mainViewController :UIViewController {
      var containerView:UIView!
}


class MyContainerView:UIViewController {
     @IBAction func buttonClick(sender:UIButton){
         // change mainViewController background for example
      }
}
```

Comment: How about some example code to help us help you? :)

Comment: Delegate, notification, direct access, ... it depends.  How are `mainViewController` and `MyContainerView` connected to each other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you are trying to get the parent controller right ?

```
self.parentViewController
```

Answer (score 2):

You should register your main view controller to listen to local notifications broadcast from your container view controller to know when it needs to perform some update function or change the UI.

In your main it would be

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "performUpdates:", name: "ContainerViewChangedUpdate", object: nil)
```

Make sure to unregister in `viewWillDisappear`.

In your container view controller you would send the notification.